# should I use delete after each new

Tags: c++

normally the object `new bar()` will be automatically destroyed after exiting the scope why I have to do a delete `pBar` then ?

```
    class bar{
      public:
      bar(){}
      //...
     };

    class foo{
        public:
        foo(){}
        void createBar(){
            bar* pBar = new bar();
            // stuff..
            delete pBar;
        }// why should I use delete and the pBar should be delted after the end of the scope ?
    };
```

also if in the function `createBar()` I add `pBar` pointer to a vector of another class. the vector has only point to the `pBar` (not owner). in this case where do I put the delete ? because if I keep it where it is it will delete the pointers then my manager vector will point to nothing ..
if I use the `delete` inside the manager class, so I will delete an object inside a non-owner class ?!

PS: I know that I can use smart pointer, but I just want to understand this point

```
void createBar(){
    bar* pBar = new bar();
    // stuff
    manager::add(pBar);
    delete pBar;
 }

class manager{
   public:
   manager(){}
   void add(bar* p){
       vFoo.push_back(p);
   }

   private:
   std::vector<bar*> vFoo;
}
```

Comment: _"the object new bar() will be automatically destroyed after exiting the scope"_  That's not correct.  Local variables will be destroyed, like your pointer.  But destroying a raw pointer does not affect the object it points to.  That's how you get a memory leak.

Comment: "normally the object new bar() will be automatically destroyed" where did you get this from?

Comment: Ideally you should not be using `new` or `delete` at all.  But yes, if every `new` is not matched with a `delete` on all exit paths, then you can have a memory leak.

Comment: Just use `bar myBar;` if you want it to autmatically get destroyed when it goes out of scope

Comment: in your last code you store a pointer to some object and then immediately destroy the object. The pointer in the vector is useless. Simply don't use raw pointers

Comment: *in this case where do I put the delete ?* -- You designed the code -- you should know where to place the `delete` call to match your design and not to create memory leaks.  No one, except yourself, would know where *exactly* you need to do this.  That's the responsibility you bring on yourself when you decide to handle dynamically allocated memory yourself.

Comment: It looks like a broken attempt at a factory.

Comment: @DrewDormann how writing `delete pBar` will destroy `bar()` object ?? according to the writing (delete pBar) it's a pointer. and supposing I'm not going to do the delete in the `createBar()` function but rather in the `manager` in this case I'm going to delete `vFoo` in this case the object `bar()` will be destroyed ? if yes then I have to follow who points to my object those that will be destroyed after the scope haliluia and the last delete I have to do it myself to ensure the release of the memory, correct ?

Comment: q.v. [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration).  *Automatic storage* is destroyed after exiting the object's scope; object lifespan is managed automatically.  *Dynamic storage* (e.g., using `new`) is destroyed explicitly by `delete`; object lifespan is managed manually.

Comment: @arturo it's probably a good time for [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  An introductory chapter should explain C++ memory management.  Stack Overflow does not work well at reproducing introductory book chapters.

Comment: @arturo You are correct that `pBar` is a pointer. Pointers are commonly used to identify to operators and functions what objects you want them to operate on. It can be used to point to the object that you want `delete` to delete. The code `delete pBar;` doesn't mean to delete `pBar` itself. It uses `pBar`'s value to identify to `delete` what object to operate on.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It's pretty clear he is misunderstanding the difference between objects being freed after they leave scope. There's no reason to be derisive toward him.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you should never ever use `new()` or `delete()`.
(Of course there are exceptions to to this, but these are very rare.)

Use the appropriate class which encapsulates the memory handling for you, like  `shared_ptr` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), or `unique_ptr` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: Yes. I try to never use `new`. There are exceptions, but always reach for `std::make_unique` first and your life will be better. In this case it’ll mean `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<bar>> vFoo;` and some `std::move` but you won’t have to worry about leaks.

Comment: You use `new` when you use a smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

How `manager` is used isn't exactly clear, but if a single `manager` object holds the pointers and no one else has them, you should write a destructor that calls `delete` on each pointer once your `manager` goes out of scope or once a pointer to `manager` has `delete` called on it.

Also, you need to create a `manager` object before using `manager::add`. As it is now, the code should generate compiler errors. For example,

```
manager m{};
m.add(pBar);
```